# Hi can you help me with importing json response with multiple values to postgres db using Python 3.8

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, postgresql, import

Json response is in following format:

```
[
    {
        "symbol": "A",
        "value": "85.44000000"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "B",
        "value": "8547.30000000"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "C",
        "value": "875.28000000"
    }
]
```

This way I can import single column into postgres db column symbol and it works well for me.

```
import pg8000
import json

resp= response.json()
json_value= json.dumps(resp)
json= json.loads (json_value)

con = pg8000.connect(user = db_user, host = db_host , database = db_name , port = db_port, password = db_pass)

for s in json:
con.run("INSERT INTO test (symbol) VALUES (:s)", s=s['symbol'])

con.commit()
con.close()
```

**I am trying this to insert both values this way, but it doesn't work:

```
for s in json:
con.run("INSERT INTO test (symbol,value) VALUES (:s)", s=s['symbol']['value'])
```

Not sure how to change the syntax to make it work so I can save symbols and values into one db table row at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list through use of square brackets with (`[s["symbol"], s["value"]]`) as in the following code's syntax

```
cur = con.cursor()
for s in json:
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO test(symbol, value) VALUES (%s, %s)", 
                        [s["symbol"], s["value"]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - you helped me much, finally it worked this way with standard brackets instead of square ones: `(s['symbol'], s['price'])`